# Call C++ class methods or function from Java on android without recreating class/variable on every call

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a pretty complex NLP code written on C++ and now I want to use it from my android app. My idea is to build app using client-server architecture, where client is an android java app, and server is a C++ Object Oriented code. But main problem for me, is that C++ components are pretty heavy (tokenizers, vectorizers, corpus data, etc) and I can't recreate them on every call, what I need is to create them once (on first request), and then have them in memory, handlind requests from java side when app is active.

Could you please give me some guidance how to achive this, since I never use C++ from Android before? Thanks in advance.

---

Java and C++ code isn't remote, there is no http or other remote requests involved, it's the same app. But to reduce ammount of overhead for inter Java/C++ communication I wan't to have a single point of contact in java code, something like `NlpEngine.sendRequest(string textToProcess, int processingWorkflowId)` and then C++ code based on `processingWorkflowId` identify, what it should do with text.

Comment: Please clarify: that C++ server is still supposed to run on the same device as the Java code? It is not a "remote server" in that sense? (where: even with that clarification; I think your question is too broad).

Comment: U want to use C++ as backend residing on remote server?

Comment: @GhostCat, yes, the same device, and the same app. The main idea just not directly calling every method, but more like send request to C++ app with text and enum, which identify what C++ code should do and get result. Like a Remote Procedure Call, but in the same app context.

Answer (score 4):

#### Assumtion

I assume you have the C++ Code compiled for Android by using a tool set like Android NDK and the front end Java app is running on the same device as the back end C++ code.

#### Java Native Calls and Session State

No matter which of the three following interfaces you use. The C/C++ Libraries are loaded and stay in memory the whole time then Java application is running. The state of the library will be preserved the whole time. I don't clearly get the concern you have about initialization. It's not like starting a command on a CLI, where the other application is started and stopped over and over.

> ... But main problem for me, is that C++ components are pretty heavy (tokenizers, vectorizers, corpus data, etc) and I can't recreate them on every call ...

#### Loading Native Libraries in Java

There are some ways to load native libraries in Java, I want to point out three:

- JNI - Java Native Interface

  JNI is a tool as old as Java itself. System calls from SWT were created using JNI. JNI is not the easy way, you have to define the functions/methods you want to make in Java as native, compile them to a C/C++ header, write the code for calling your library in this intermediate library. Compile this code for every ABI Platform ([There are 7 Androids ABIs according to NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)). In the Java program you have find out the platform to call the ABI suitable intermediate library. JNI has many other pitfalls.
- [JNA - Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

  [JNA] is a java library that dynamically loads the C/C++ library by reflection. The definition of the Java call is done in pure java with no extra tool. The ease of usage has a trade-off in performance, the overhead of calling a function is up to 10 times slower than JNI. But that only plays a roll if you are calling extreme short running C/C++ library functions/methods very often. In your case it sound like you just call a few time the functions and these functions will take there time to run. JNA is used by Android developers.
- [JNR-FFI - Java Native Runtime](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi)

  JNR-FFI is the newest candidate. JNR-FFI is the part you use to call libraries.The other parts are the baseline for JNR-FFI. It's very much inspired by JNA. Java code developed with JNA and with JNR-FFI looks very similar. The reason JNR-FFI was developed is performance. In general JNR-FFI is a little slower than JNI (for getpid approx. 15%) but under some circumstances it can be faster than JNI. In the case of a long runtime on the C/C++ side this overhead does not matter. JNR is proposed to be in Java 9 as Standard Library [JEP 191: Foreign Function Interface](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/191). The caveats: JNR-FFI seams to have some problems with Android.

#### Personal Experience

I had to implement some native library calls from Java. I started with JNI and after a week of testing an studying there were only few demo lines that worked. Every try took a long time, different tools, long building time. Than I found a presentation about the pitfalls of JNI and what side effects had to be considered. ...

I found JNA. Within a few hours the first demo code with my library worked and compared to JNI it is so lightweight and fast in development. I switched to JNR-FFI because it was the modern version of JNA. For what I did the performance was not the reason to switch, it was only a positive side effect.

I did not develop with JNA or JNR-FFI under Android. But in your case I would give JNA a try, because it is better supported with Android. I hopefully JNR-FFI gets implemented in Java 9 it is ease to switch from JNA code to a JNR-FFI code.

#### Example

I added and example of JNR-FFI to give you an idea of the ease of use. There is nothing more to do than to implement this few lines to be able to call a native c-library function.

JNR-FFI Example taken from [Java Native Runtime - The Missing Link by Charles Oliver Nutter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013nutter-2013526.pdf)

```
public class GetPidJNRExample {
    public interface GetPid {
        @IgnoreError
        long getpid();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        LibraryLoader<GetPid> loader =
            FFIProvider
                .getSystemProvider()
                .createLibraryLoader(GetPid.class);

        GetPid getpid = loader.load("c");

        getpid.getpid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but "good" answers do contain a brief summery of the linked sites; you know: links can go down; and then your "hmm, ok" answer because pretty much useless.

Comment: AFAIK you can load DLLs also by the regular JNI. In the fact, if I remember well I was last working with JNI, the JNI calls are normally provided by a DLL (which remains loaded in the Java app, so there shouldn't be much problem to keep a state).

Comment: @notes-jj Thanks for the answer. I will investigate different options. However you mentioned that in JNI case required to compile libs for different platforms (x86, arm, etc and you mention that it's a problem). Is it not required in jna/jnr cases? I don't see how this could be avoided.

Comment: @silent_coder JNI - Yes, you have to compile for every platform. JNA and JNR-FFI use libffi as foundation. The interface to talk to libffi is based on JNI, but the projects did that for you so you don't have to touch JNI at all. The jar/aar file from the Projects contain these binaries for the platforms. JNA uses this interface to do reflection on os level. JNR-FFI is the freakiest approach. It dynamically creates machine code for the function call on startup and executes it on the os level. So for the Java side of programming you don't need any extra/unusual tool chain or compilers.